# Change Column If Exists

Tags: mariadb

Apparently MariaDB supports `IF EXISTS` in conjunction with `CHANGE` for `ALTER TABLE queries (https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/alter-table/) however the *detailed* documentation does not imply this.
 Here are a couple of example queries for a test table:

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE COLUMN `col2` `col2` INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER `col1`;

ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE COLUMN `col2` `col2` INT(2) NOT NULL AFTER `col1`;
```

However when I add `IF EXISTS` MariaDB throws a sytax error:

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE COLUMN `col2` IF EXISTS `col2` INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER `col1`;
```

Yes, apparently this is not part of the SQL standard (and in my scenario I do not have to be concerned with that or compatibility with MySQL). However I *am* interested in a more explicit yes or no in support for `IF EXISTS` specifically in conjunction with `CHANGE` and *if* so how the proper syntax would look? Locally I'm using MariaDB 10.2.6.

Comment: Side note:  The `(1)` or `(2)` means nothing; I hope you were not making _that_ change!

Comment: @RickJames No and thank you, I just wanted to avoid a horizontal scrollbar and not have yet another thread get completely derailed for something frivolous. :-) Using `INT()` is valid then?

Comment: Just plain `INT` is sufficient.  It means a 4-byte signed number, regardless of the parens.  `SHOW CREATE TABLE` adds `(11)`, but nothing uses it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Incorrect**

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE COLUMN `col2` IF EXISTS `col2` INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER `col1`;
```

**Incorrect**

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE COLUMN `col2` `col2` IF EXISTS INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER `col1`;
```

**Correct**

```
ALTER TABLE `test` CHANGE COLUMN IF EXISTS `col2` `col2` INT(1) NOT NULL AFTER `col1`;
```

The `IF EXISTS` *must* immediately follow `CHANGE COLUMN`.